# If he did or if he had

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Consider the following excerpt:

> He couldn't follow. Just couldn't. Because if he **had**, he would have been [...]

As a non-native speaker, I am unsure about whether to use either *did* or *had* to express what would have been if the character followed.

What is correct or could one use both?

Comment: This is just personal opinion so I won't post it as an answer, but I think that both are acceptable but "did" would be better. Usually with sentences like this, I mentally insert the verb that's being referenced to make sure it still makes sense, so in this case it would be "Because if he did (follow), he would be x". However, you could arguably use "had" with the mutation of the verb being implied. To wit, "Because if he had (followed), he would have been x".

Answer (score 4):

The difference between "If he did" and "If he had" is the same as the difference between the forms they are ellipsised for: "If he did follow" (or "If he followed") and "If he had followed".

The difference between these is that "If he had"( = "If he had followed") is *irrealis* (or counterfactual): it makes explicit that he didn't follow, and that this is a hypothetical.

"If he did" (= "If he followed") is not *irrealis*: it leaves open whether or not he followed.

In this case, given what precedes, we know that he did not follow, so there is no practical difference. But in other circumstances there might be. "If he had" implies that the speaker knows that he didn't, but "If he did", does not have that implication.

Comment: I think it's worth noting 32 matches for [didn't happen because if it **did**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22didn%27t+happen+because+if+it+did%22) in Google Books, as against just 8 for [didn't happen because if it **had**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22didn%27t+happen+because+if+it+had%22). It's a little curious considering the context makes it clear we're talking about a counterfactual rather than a "not-yet-known" postulated past (which as you say is more explicitly conveyed by ***had***).